# Can't get access_token with MSAL/React

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get an access token using MSAL and React using Azure B2C. I have configured B2C applications with permissions, scope, and setup a user flow, and I am able to login and get an `id_token`, but the `AuthenticationResult` never contains an `access_token` and is never set on subsequent requests.

[image]

After logging in, here is code to get an access_token:

```
export async function getAccessToken(){

    const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    const accessTokenRequest = {
        scopes: ["https://<my api uri>/api.full_access"],
        account: account,
    }
    var response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
        accessTokenRequest,
        account: account
    });

    return response;
}
```

@azure/msal-browser = ^3.0.1
@azure/msal-react = 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to now call initialize since version 2 if doing this outside of react.

I.e.

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)
await msalInstance.initialize()
```